# How do I remove part of the HTML code with TWIG?

Tags: html, drupal, twig, drupal-8

In my Drupal 8 template, I have the following TWIG code :

```
{{ product.variations }}
```

It displays the following HTML code :

```
<div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions js-form-wrapper form-group" id="edit-actions--2">

  <button class="button--add-to-cart button button--primary js-form-submit form-submit btn btn-primary" data-drupal-selector="edit-submit" type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Ajouter au panier">Ajouter au panier</button>

  <span>Ajouter au panier</span>

</div>
```

How to remove the whole  ...  line from HTML code in TWIG ?

I tried the code below, but the button is still showing :

```
{{ product.variations|without('button', 'submit') }}
```

Comment: You should dump `product.variations` to see the data structure inside

Answer (score 0):

Strip the tags with `striptags` filter.

```
{{ some_html|striptags('<br><p>') }}
```

or in your case

```
{{ product.variations|striptags('<button><submit>') }}
```